# 'templatedUrls' when upgrading from v2 to v3

Tags: workbox

I was using v2 of Workbox, and am now upgrading to v3. I generate it using Webpack.

I've begun using GenerateSW, and moving parts of the old config into the new one, changing where required for v3.

I'm running into a bug with `templatedUrls` not seeming to work the same way it did in v2.

Webpack config:

```
plugins: [
    new WorkboxPlugin.GenerateSW({
        include: [/\.css$/, /\.js$/, /sprites\\.svg$/],
        importsDirectory: path.join(__dirname, 'public/precache'),
        'clientsClaim': true,
        'skipWaiting': true,
        'templatedUrls': {
            '/': ['resources/views/index.blade.php', 'resources/views/scripts.blade.php']
        },
        navigateFallback: '/'
    })
]
```

Error:

```
There was an issue using one of the provided 'templatedUrls'. 'resources/views/index.blade.php' from '{"/":["resources/views/index.blade.php","resources/views/scripts.blade.php"]}':
Error: An error occurred when globbing for files. 'The "path" argument must be of type string'
    at .../node_modules/workbox-build/build/lib/get-file-manifest-entries.js:138:27
```

If I use a string instead of an array, it works fine, but this is obviously for manual versioning rather than an array of file paths, which is what I am attempting to do here.

Furthermore, even changing it to my index.php file yields the same problem:

```
There was an issue using one of the provided 'templatedUrls'. 'index.php' from '{"/":["index.php"]}':
Error: An error occurred when globbing for files. 'The "path" argument must be of type string'
```

---

Finally, if I add `globDirectory: 'public',` just before it, it seems to work, and expects my URLs to be based on that public directory (`../resources...`). However, it gives me this warning:

```
WARNING in You're using the following Workbox configuration 
option: [globDirectory]. In Workbox v3 and later, this is usually not needed.
```

There doesn't seem to be any mention of this key being required in the docs.

Any advice would be thoroughly appreciated!

Comment: resources/views/scripts.blade.php     is that path correct? review the docs for pairing templates with scripts

Comment: Yep, I believe the paths are correct, and the syntax I've used matches that in the docs. The Scripts blade template isn't special, it's just some HTML I've separated out. Can just ignore it. The above works fine when the globDirectory is added. Is there a way to check what directory it is attempting to match the paths from? E.g. is it the root of the webpack directory, or the build directory, etc? Both of which don't seem to work until a globDirectory is added

Comment: I've now run into this problem again in a separate project, where my template URLs are 'header.php' and 'footer.php'. Same error message, and adding a globDirectory lets it work, but spits out that warning. Is there a new way to handle templatedUrls that I'm missing? Or is this still correct?